# Inline editor for nodes and edges in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is there a way to display an inline editor (i.e. a textbox) when the user double clicks a node or an edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) You can show a textbox on click by positioning the textbox based on the node's [rendered position](http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/position--dimensions/node.renderedPosition).  There is no double click built-in event, because double clicks preclude touch support.  Users rarely double click on desktop, and they nearly never double tap on touch.

(2) You may want to reuse your textbox code as an [extension](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions) with parameterised options.

(3) If you have more content to put along the textbox or otherwise prefer, you may want to place the textbox in a qtip using the [qtip extension](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip).